# Dropbox keep on syncing on restart

Tags: sync, dropbox, deep-freeze

I installed Dropbox in "D drive" and I have DeepFreeze install for "C drive". With DeepFreeze if I restart my computer, my computer will automatically come to previous state, as I need to install any important software or files by turning it off else it will wipe them off on restart and this will prevent my computer from virus and software testing.

Just because DeepFreeze roll backs C drive upon every restart, I installed Dropbox in D drive in order to not to loose files and its all good, my files are safe now.

But, for example if I have 10000 files in my dropbox, every time I restart my computer, its syncing all 10000 files, though those files are in the system, its still downloading the files list and doing the check on every restart and this is taking almost 12 hours as I have too many files in dropbox.

I believe this is because, there is some temporary files related to dropbox are located in C drive and they are removed and recreated upon restart, is there anyway that I can move that dropbox temporary sync files or folders too to D drive?

Answer (score 0):

Deep Freeze is playing games with your files my good friend! Those temp files are quite big, and DF is convincing your computer that they exist when in all fairness they are being buffered in a temp directory.

If my memory is correct DF won't let you exclude folders from the process, hence you're going to get this problem you need to basically convince the program to ignore that folder, moving it to D drive is tricky as you'll need to exclude it. Try looking at Drive vaccine i use that and it has an exclusion drive option that you could place those dropbox temp files into and they won't be restored everytime.